# Ошибка с openCV2

Tags: python, opencv

Написал такой код

```
import cv2
import face_recognition


def face_rec():
    extracting_faces('images/to_recognition/2.jpg')

def extracting_faces(path):
    image = cv2.imread(path) 
    face_coor = face_recognition.face_locations(image)
    for x,y,w,h in face_coor:
        extract_img = image[y:h,x:w]
        print(extract_img)
        cv2.imshow('Result image', extract_img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

def main():
    face_rec()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Код тупо берет путь к фотографии с лицом человека и обрезает ее именно в области лица. Путь правильный, но все же возникает ошибка

```
  File "тут путь к файлу", line 15, in extracting_faces
    cv2.imshow('Result image', extract_img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4-dev) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Comment: Тогда переименуйте переменные, `w` и `h` сбивает с толку, назовите нормально `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left` и, главное, напечатайте их перед тем, как сделать срез, может понятнее что станет. Может вы не в том порядке в срезе их используете. Например, `right` и `left` должны явно как `left:right` использоваться в срезе. Понять бы ещё, где там начало координат.

Comment: Во-первых, удостоверьтесь, что входная картинка в переменной `image` не пустая. Например, `imread()` очень привередлив и не работает с русскими именами в путях. Причём не выдаёт никаких ошибок при этом. Ну и банально можно проверить "на пустоту" `extract_img` прежде чем идти дальше,

Comment: @GrAnd Проверять нужно, но ошибка то дальше, я думаю с пустым имиджем ничего бы не нашлось и в цикл не вошло бы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had this problem a few days ago . just make sure file is in the correct folder and ahs the correct name and extension

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).